# joda-time or joda-time-android Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, jodatime

I have build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
  applicationId "com.xcompany.xapplication"
  minSdkVersion 15
  targetSdkVersion 23
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
  release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }
}

packagingOptions {
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'  
  compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
}
```

When I try to make apk and run the application error occurs:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

It looks like proguard configuration problem, but settings for joda classes in proguard-rules.pro does not help.

My Proguard Configuration:

```
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding **multiDexEnabled true** to defaultConfig section of build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
  applicationId "com.xcompany.xapplication"
  multiDexEnabled true      
  minSdkVersion 15
  targetSdkVersion 23
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"
}
```

I found solution [here](http://www.techgig.com/question/49218/retrolambda-requirement-java-8-causing-mobile-dexdebug-39-exception).